# Is it possible to call ternary expression as a function call?

Tags: javascript

I saw this piece of code inside a project, and the following lines of codes got me disturbed

```
function toggleClass(elem, c) {
    var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
    fn(elem, c); 
}
```

My confusion is that the variable fn is being called on the third line, but it is hardly a function. What am i missing here.

Comment: In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects.You don't need to do anything special to pass them around just like any other variable in JavaScript.

Comment: What is "hardly a function" supposed to mean? What is it if not a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not. Ternary operator checks the condition and returns the appropriate value for that case. The value can be also a reference to the function. You can try it yourself.

Your `fn` is called then you execute it via `()`.

Ternary operator does this. If the condition returns `true`, **the reference of the removeClass** is assigned to the `fn`. This just copies the reference and put it into the `fn` variable - doesn't execute it. The same is done when the condition returns `false`. After this when you call `fn()`, `fn` contains the reference to a function, which ternary returns. It goes via that reference and call the appropriate function.

```js
function remove() {
  console.log('Remove');
}

function add() {
  console.log('Add');
}

function toggle(data){
  var fn = data ? remove : add;
  fn();
}

toggle(true);
toggle(false);
```

Comment: I think OP's code is working fine. He/she is looking for an explanation as to why `fn` calls necessary function.

Answer (score 2):

For an easier explanation, the given code is equivalent to following:

```
removeClass(elem, c) {
    // removes class 'c' from element 'elem'
}

addClass(elem, c) {
    // adds class 'c' in element 'elem'
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
    var fn;
    if( hasClass( elem, c ) )
        fn = removeClass;
    else
        fn = addClass;
    fn( elem, c ); 
}
```

Functions are basically objects in javascript, and functions can be assigned to variables. In current case, the variable is `fn`.

Answer (score 1):

You could even call the result of the ternay directly, because the [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) returns the expression depending on the condition.

```
(hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass)(elem, c);
```

The assignment of a function (reference) to a variable is the first part of choosing a suitable function for the second part of calling this function.

The code it is shorter then a standard `if ... then ... else` syntax.

Comment: I think OP's code is working fine. He/she is looking for an explanation as to why `fn` calls necessary function.

Answer (score 1):

> My confusion is that the variable fn is being called on the third line, but it is hardly a function. What am i missing here.

Functions are objects in Javascript and objects are copied using reference. What does this mean?

When you define a function say `addClass`, it is stored in a memory location say *x1001*. Here, `addClass` will hold this memory location and when its followed by `()` the code it picked from this location and executed.

When you do `var fn = addClass`, you are just copying this reference. So now `fn` also has *x1001* and not actual function. Hence when you do `fn()`, you are able to call necessary function.

Hope it helps!

Comment: **Note:** If you think there is anything wrong with above answer, please comment along with your vote. Have a good day!

Comment: thank yo very much pal, I think you and others here have just helped joggle my memory. Surely I am grateful